# margin-top for grid columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I need to make grid structure like on image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6Mxg.png)

I use this solution for 4 columns on desktop, but for mobile I need 3 cols. And in this solution I can't make different margins for columns

```
.gallery__wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.img_wrapper:nth-of-type(even) {
  top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
```

UPD: For 3 columns I use but I can't use nth-of-type(even)

```
.gallery__wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;

}
```

Comment: You can use media query and change that.

Comment: I know how to use media query, I asked about modifying css grid for 3 columns. May be my explanation is not so good

Comment: Mmmh, just remove a column and put into a media query? so when mobile user open will see three column?

Comment: Question is not how to show 3 columns. It's about making top margins for columns like in attached image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your question. I was able to create a gallery with 3 columns and a margin using your code. What is the Problem?

Since you didn't provide any HTML I had to guess and created my own.

```css
    .gallery__wrapper {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      grid-gap: 1em;
    }
    .img_wrapper {
      background-color: #123456;
      min-width: 180px;
      min-height: 360px;
    }
    .img_wrapper:nth-of-type(even) {
      /**
       * Using margin-top: 20px;
       * also works here
       */
      position: relative;
      top: 20px;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="gallery__wrapper">
    <div class="img_wrapper"></div>
    <div class="img_wrapper"></div>
    <div class="img_wrapper"></div>
    <div class="img_wrapper"></div>
    <div class="img_wrapper"></div>
    <div class="img_wrapper"></div>
    <div class="img_wrapper"></div>
    <div class="img_wrapper"></div>
    <div class="img_wrapper"></div>
    <div class="img_wrapper"></div>
    <div class="img_wrapper"></div>
    <div class="img_wrapper"></div>
    <div class="img_wrapper"></div>
    <div class="img_wrapper"></div>
    <div class="img_wrapper"></div>
    <div class="img_wrapper"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: That's actually not that I expect. Please look to example picture. All items should have same dimensions. And columns should have different margins.